# Strange error with cuda::reprojectImageTo3D and OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Hello I am trying to get a Mat with the XYZ cordenates from a disparity map that i have already generated with a cuda::StereoBM object, this is a screenshot of the disparity map I created ["disparity map"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zskhb.jpg) 
but when I add the function cuda::reprojectImageTo3D(d_disp,d_xyz,d_Q,3,Stream); I get an error I can't understand, if I coment this line of code no error is shown but the moment I try to use this function I get the next [error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEcRt.jpg)

and the error code is:

`OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented (You should explicitly call download method for cuda::GpuMat object) in cv::_InputArray::getMat_, file C:\opencv\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1211`

bellow is my code, note that most of my Mats are declared as global , so their declarations are not in this slot function

```
void MainWindow::on_botonMostrarDispSGBMCUDA_clicked()
{

    if(map_l1.empty()&&map_l2.empty()&&map_r1.empty() &&map_r2.empty()){
        FileStorage fs(xmlname,FileStorage::READ);
        fs["map_l1"]>>map_l1;
        fs["map_l2"]>>map_l2;
        fs["map_r1"]>>map_r1;
        fs["map_r2"]>>map_r2;
        fs["Q"] >> Q;
        fs.release();
    }
    Mat img1, img2;
    img1 = imread("C:\\Users\\Diego\\Pictures\\calibstereo\\camleft\\photoleft_1.jpg");
    img2 = imread("C:\\Users\\Diego\\Pictures\\calibstereo\\camright\\photoright_1.jpg");


    cvtColor(img1, frameLGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(img2, frameRGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    remap(frameLGray,framel_rect,map_l1,map_l2,INTER_LINEAR);
    remap(frameRGray,framer_rect,map_r1,map_r2,INTER_LINEAR);

    bool ok1, ok2, ok3, ok4, ok5, ok6 , ok7,ok8,ok9,ok10 ;
    int preFilterSize = ui->editPrefilterSizeBM->text().toInt(&ok1);
    int prefilterCap = ui->editFilterCapBM->text().toInt(&ok2);
    int blockSize = ui->editBlockSBM->text().toInt(&ok3);
    int minDisp = ui->editMinDispBM->text().toInt(&ok4);
    int numDisp = ui->editNumDispBM->text().toInt(&ok5);
    int texturethresh = ui->editTextureBM->text().toInt(&ok6);
    int uniqueness = ui->editUniquenesBM->text().toInt(&ok7);
    int speckleWindow = ui->editSpeckleWindowBM->text().toInt(&ok8);
    int speckleRange = ui->editSpeckleRangeBM->text().toInt(&ok9);
    int maxDiff = ui->editMaxDiffBM->text().toInt(&ok10);

    if (!ok1 || !ok2 || !ok3 || !ok4 || !ok5 || !ok6 || !ok7 || !ok8 || !ok9 || !ok10){
        QMessageBox messageBox;
        messageBox.setIconPixmap(QPixmap(":/icon.svg"));
        messageBox.setText("One of your entries is not a valid number.");
        messageBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
        messageBox.exec();
     }


    d_left.upload(framel_rect);
    d_right.upload(framer_rect);
    Ptr<cuda::StereoBM> CUSBM;
    CUSBM = cuda::createStereoBM(64, 5);
    CUSBM->setPreFilterSize(preFilterSize);             
    CUSBM->setPreFilterCap(prefilterCap);               
    CUSBM->setBlockSize(blockSize);                     
    CUSBM->setMinDisparity(minDisp);                    
    CUSBM->setNumDisparities(numDisp);                  
    CUSBM->setTextureThreshold(texturethresh);          
    CUSBM->setUniquenessRatio(uniqueness);              
    CUSBM->setSpeckleWindowSize(speckleWindow);         
    CUSBM->setSpeckleRange(speckleRange);               
    CUSBM->setDisp12MaxDiff(maxDiff);                   
    cuda::Stream myStream = cuda::Stream::Stream();
    CUSBM->compute(d_left, d_right, d_disp, myStream);
    if(!d_disp.empty()){
        cuda::GpuMat d_xyz(d_disp.size(), CV_32FC4);
        cuda::GpuMat d_Q(4,4,CV_32F);
        d_Q.upload(Q);
        cuda::Stream mySecondStream = cuda::Stream::Stream();
        cuda::reprojectImageTo3D(d_disp,d_xyz,d_Q,3,mySecondStream);
        d_xyz.download(xyz);
    }

    cuda::drawColorDisp(d_disp, d_disp,numDisp);        //64

    d_disp.download(disp);

    namedWindow("left");
    namedWindow("right");
    namedWindow("disp");

    imshow("left", framel_rect);
    imshow("right", framer_rect);
    imshow("disp", disp);
    //imshow("xyz", xyz);
    waitKey(0);
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
}
```

I am using Windows 8.1, QtCreator as my IDE, OpenCV 3.0.0 with cuda 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `d_disp` in line `cuda::reprojectImageTo3D(d_disp,d_xyz,d_Q,3,mySecondStream);` is a [`GpuMat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#gpu-reprojectimageto3d)

Your problem may from `cv::Mat` class, it has no overloaded assignment operator or copy constructor which takes argument of type `cv::gpu::GpuMat`, so you are not able to mix them in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I have it declared as a global outside this slot function, along with d_left and d_right, but it wont work :(
'cuda::GpuMat d_left, d_right, d_disp;'

Answer (score 0):

I checked the the argument list for the function from *cudastereo/src/util.cpp*.

The function seems to take `d_disp` and `d_xyz` as `cuda::GpuMat`, but the Q matrix needs to be a `cv::Mat`.

`cuda::reprojectImageTo3D(d_disp,d_xyz,Q,3,mySecondStream);` seems to work fine.

Sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `cuda::drawColorDisp(d_disp, d_disp,numDisp);        //64`. You are supplying same source and destination `GpuMat` files, which **should not be the case**. You may like to have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d47/group__cudastereo.html#ga469b23a77938dd7c06861e59cecc08c5) for the detailed constructor arguments for `drawColorDisp`.